# react-native-vlc-media-player: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7

Tags: react-native

- [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ9q0.png)
- i tried to update android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

This is my Environment, variables

- [Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKX9c.png)
- [Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6alo.png)
- node version: 16.13.2
- react-native-vlc-media-player: 1.0.60

Comment: my java version: openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16 LTS